# Some images cannot be opened when reduced in size and byte

Tags: php

I want to display several thumbnails on the website using the script code below. So far it seems to be working, but strangely there are some images that won't display.

I have tried several times but failed. Here's the script that I saved in the thumbnail.php file

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['width'], $_GET['height'], $_GET['url'])) {
       $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['url']);
       $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
       $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
       $dest_imagex = $_GET['width'];
       $dest_imagey = $_GET['height'];
       $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
       imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
       header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
       imagejpeg($dest_image,NULL,100);
}
?>
```

I provided 2 sample images, 1 of which loaded, and the other failed to load.

`https://www.chordband.com/article_data/thumbnail.php?url=https://www.chordband.com/article_data/media/images/2023/07/0506_Taylor%20Swift%20Holds%20-%20I%20Can%20See%20You%20Concert.jpg&width=100&height=50 // Error`

`https://www.chordband.com/article_data/thumbnail.php?url=https://www.chordband.com/article_data/media/images/2023/07/1041_Soprano%20Singer%20Lee%20Sang%20Eun%20Dies%20in%20Bathroom%20Before%20Concert.jpg&width=100&height=50 // Working`

If I open an image that fails to load directly, for example `https://www.chordband.com/article_data/media/images/2023/07/0506_Taylor%20Swift%20Holds%20-%20I%20Can%20See%20You%20Concert.jpg` then the image can be opened.

I believe there is something wrong with my mechanism, and I need your help to solve this problem. Any information would be appreciated, thank you.

The problem: the image only displays a black background, not the actual image.
I want all images to be able to be opened using that php code

Comment: _"If I open an image that fails to load directly, for example [...] then the image can be opened."_ - not here on my end, I am getting a 404 response when I copy&paste that exact example URL you have given into my browser.

Comment: Btw, the actual `url` parameter value you are passing there, is `https://www.chordband.com/article_data/media/images/2023/07/0506_Taylor Swift Holds - I Can See You Concert.jpg` - _without_ any percent encoding of spaces. You would need to encode the URL that already contains the correct URL encoding in the relevant places, _again_ as a whole - because you are inserting it as a parameter value into _another_ URL there.

Comment: But since all the examples you have given appear to use images from the same system this resizer script belongs to, question would be why you are using URLs in the first place, instead of file names. You are adding the overhead of an extra HTTP request each time.

Comment: for me it doesn't work "If I open an image that fails to load directly, for example https://www.chordband.com/article_data/media/images/2023/07/0506_Taylor%20Swift%20Holds%20-%20I%20Can%20See%20You%20Concert.jpg then the image can be opened."